# CW approximation

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I was reading several proofs of the CW approximation theorem. If $X$ is a space then the idea is to make $n$-equivalences $f_n:K_n \to X$ where $K_n$ is a $n$-dimensional CW-complex. This goes by induction. Given $f_n$, the first part consists of making $f_{n+1}'$ on $K_{n+1}'$ where $K_{n+1}'$ is obtained by attaching $(n+1)$-cells along representatives in the kernel of $f_{n*}:\pi_{n}(K_n) \to \pi_{n}(X)$.

For the second part, to obtain $K_{n+1}$, one again attaches $(n+1)$-cells along constant maps, which is the same as taking the wedge of $K_{n+1}'$ and a bunch of $S^{n+1}$. This is where I get confused. Reading http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT-CWapprox.pdf for example, It seems that we attach for each generator of $\pi_{n+1}(X)$ a sphere $S^{n+1}$. In other proofs I read that we only attach for generators of the cokernel of $f_{n+1*}':\pi_{n+1}(K_{n+1}') \to \pi_{n+1}(X)$.

Does this make a difference ?

Comment: One can do this more or less efficiently. For example, you could also attach one cell for each element of $\pi_{n+1}$. The only important thing is to attach enough cells so as to do what one wants: kill the appropriate homotopy group.

Comment: Okay, and I guess it is then also not necessary to consider generators and one could instead attach cells for each representative of each class which is in consideration.

Comment: Since the price of each cell is very very low ($0) and we have them in great supply, it does not really matter how many cells we use, even if we are "wasting" them. But sometimes one wants to have approximations with as few cells as possible for various reasons, and then it is good to know that one can cut down the numbr of cells in various ways.

Comment: Indeed. You can even attach *more* cells than needed, thereby creating a problem (you get a larger homotopy group in the next dimension!) but you solve it by attaching even more cells one dimension up. For example, you can build absurdly complicated CW approximations of the one point space :-)